# problems for install ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, lenovo, iso, usb-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop, but when I restart with the USB drive, the installation doesn't start. It's like the USB drive doesn't exist. My device specifications are:

- Device name: DESKTOP-S5J52U9
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz 1.70GHz
- Installed RAM: 8.00 GB
- System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor.

thanks.

Comment: Either the creation of the live usb is not ok (be sure the OS ISO is fine too and then use something that can be trusted like [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher)), or the laptop has a key or key-combination that must be used for the USB-boot to happen. Google `key to boot usb lenovo`.

Comment: Please be specific with details; Ubuntu provides many products/releases & for some choices in ISO, and you gave no actual specifics of what you tried. Five different installers are available (*selected by ISO you download*) for example, and your provided details don't rule out user procedural errors (did you verify ISO after download? was it written correctly? have you verified ISO write to your media as per your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release etc) plus used the specific key for your device to boot external media.

Comment: I'm new to linux in general and honestly, I don't know how to verify the ISO.

Comment: After download you can use https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 to ensure the ISO was downloaded correctly (*this is rarely a problem in my experience*). Next you write the ISO to media using an appropriate tool, and I can not provide links for here on as you gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu product, what release of that product etc.. eg. are you talking about Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? a *flavor* of Ubuntu etc (*though flavors are identical to Ubuntu Desktop*)... and what release of that *unstated* product...

Comment: the ubuntu's file dowloaded is: ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.

Comment: @SergiNavarro. How did you make the USB drive bootable with Ubuntu? Which method/tool? Can you check that it works in some other computer? Anyway, I would use a light-weight Ubuntu community flavour: Lubuntu or Xubuntu in that computer, and I would use the version with long time support, now 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)